# Why do I need to declare a private class static to avoid the "Generic Array Creation" error?

Tags: java, generics

The following code snippet throws the error: " Generic array creation" despite not having any generic instances within the Node class. However, if i declare the private class Node as static , the error goes away. Why is the static keyword important here?

```
 public class SeperateChainingST<Key, Value>{

        private int M =97;
        private Node[] st = new Node[M];

        private class Node{
            Object key;
            Object val;
            Node next;
        }
    }
```

Comment: do not you need to define Node class first and use it after?

Comment: I don't believe this code does this.

Comment: @KickButtowski No, Java doesn't have obnoxious forward-declaration rules.

Comment: @chrylis wowwwwwww cool always learn something new thank you :)

Comment: Maybe this will help you a little http://stackoverflow.com/a/26452098/1393766. In short you could try to use `private SeperateChainingST.Node[] st = new SeperateChainingST.Node[M];` but using raw types is discouraged. Instead you should use collection like `private List<SeperateChainingST<Key, Value>.Node> list = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Also consider actually changing types of Node fields `key`, `val` to actually use generic types of your `SeperateChainingST` class (otherwise what is the point of having them?). So instead of `Object` you can use `Key key`, `Value val`.

Comment: @Pshemo But using generic types for array creation is disallowed in Java. It throws the same exception: "Generic array creation" error

Comment: I didn't use generic type while creating array, I used raw type (which is considered as errorprone so compiler give us *warning* about it, not *error*). I used then with lists.

Comment: @Pshemo I will try this with Lists then. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Node` is a non-static nested class. That means it is an *inner* class, and it is within the scope of the type parameters `Key` and `Value` of its outer class.

When you simply write the type `Node` without any explicitly qualification inside `SeperateChainingST`, it is implicitly qualified as `SeperateChainingST<Key, Value>.Node`. This is a parameterized type (it has the type parameters `Key` and `Value`), even though you do not "see" them when writing `Node`.

As you know, you cannot use array creation expression with a component type that is a parameterized type:

```
new HashMap<Key, Value>[5]
```

So you cannot do

```
new Node[5] // which is equivalent to
new SeperateChainingST<Key, Value>.Node[5]
```

But, as you may also know, array creation expression can be used with a component type that is a raw type, or a type that is parameterized with all wildcards:

```
new HashMap[5]
new HashMap<?,?>[5]
```

We can do it similarly here, except how do you get the raw type of the inner class `Node`? It is not just `Node`, as we have found. Instead, you must explicitly qualify it with the raw type of the outer class:

```
new SeperateChainingST.Node[5]
```

or with the all-wildcards way:

```
new SeperateChainingST<?,?>.Node[5]
```